Passing `ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs` to ViewModel function as parameter in .NET MAUI 8
I'm encountering a challenge in .NET MAUI involving passing event arguments to a function in the ViewModel. Specifically, I need to access the LastVisibleItemIndex property from ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs triggered by the Scrolled event in a CollectionView. This property is crucial for my task's implementation.
<CollectionView.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
        EventName="Scrolled"
        Command="{Binding ScrolledCommand}"
        CommandParameter="Is There a way to pass it here ?" />
</CollectionView.Behaviors>

I have tried many thing but none of them seem to be working as i tought it would be.
Also i have heard something about AttachedProperties but this seems to but out of my range of knowledge
Im trying to achive something like that in my viewmodel.
[RelayCommand]
public void OnScrolled(ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
{
   //code
}


Yes, sort of. You can access the event arguments, but in your case, you'll probably want to write a converter for this as to not break the MVVM pattern.

seems to be solving my problem, thanks.
i have read this article 2 times but must ve missed x:TypeArguments

Why would you want your View's code in your VM, At this point just do this in your .xaml.cs file

@FreakyAli cause i dont want to break mvvm patter.

Please enlighten me how that breaks MVVM
